# How to batch delete embedded covers from FLAC files

Tags: audio, flac

I came across a thread which discusses the way covers should be removed.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1162249

These two commands seem to do the job:

```
metaflac --remove --block-type=PICTURE,PADDING --dont-use-padding "/tmp/del/test.flac"
metaflac --remove-tag=COVERART  --dont-use-padding "/tmp/del/test.flac"
```

The thing is that I would like to apply them to the whole directory, because I have 10 songs and all of them needs the covers removed. Any idea how can I do that?

UPDATE: I'm on Linux.

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: I'm using Fedora Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux shells, if we use the asterisk wildcard (e.g. `*.flac`) for file names metaflac will treat the entire directory as an album so...

```
metaflac --remove --block-type=PICTURE,PADDING --dont-use-padding *.flac
metaflac --remove-tag=COVERART  --dont-use-padding *.flac
```